# Underscore.js `filter` not working

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following code snippet I use to choose which suburbs from a list the user has selected (with irrelevant code omitted):

```
var allSuburbsList = new Array([{"SuburbID":1,"SuburbAreaID":3,"SuburbName":"Alberante","SuburbActive":true,"Area":null,"Agents":[]},{"SuburbID":4,"SuburbAreaID":3,"SuburbName":"Alberton North","SuburbActive":true,"Area":null,"Agents":[]}]);

var a3burbs = _.filter(allSuburbsList, function(s) { return s.SuburbAreaID === 3; }); 
// 3 is a test value. All the test suburbs so far fall under area no. 3.
```

With this filter, `a3burbs` comes out as an empty array, `[]`. If I cheat and make the filter:

```
var a3burbs = _.filter(allSuburbsList, function(s) { return true; });
```

then `a3bubrs` comes out an exact copy of `allSuburbsList`, with all suburbs included. What could I be doing wrong? I'm using the same syntax as indicated on the Underscore.js home page.

Btw, would the way I populate `allSuburbsList` from a viewmodel array property have anything to do with this:

```
var allSuburbsList = new Array(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllSuburbs)));
```

Just for interest, my first attempt was the hideous code below, but it worked:

```
var a3burbs = [];
@{for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllSuburbs.Length; i++) {
    @:if (allSuburbsList[@i].SuburbAreaID === 3) {
        @:a3burbs.push(allSuburbsList[@i]);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new array **and** passing in an array.

Change it to

```
var allSuburbsList = [{"SuburbID":1,"SuburbAreaID":3,"SuburbName":"Alberante","SuburbActive":true,"Area":null,"Agents":[]},{"SuburbID":4,"SuburbAreaID":3,"SuburbName":"Alberton North","SuburbActive":true,"Area":null,"Agents":[]}];
```

Comment: It isn't literal JS, it's rendered by the Razor code I added at the end of my question. I can't change the statement you cite.

Comment: In the absolute *worst* case scenario you can do `_.filter(allSuburbsList[0],...` but I would **highly** recommend you find a way to modify the generated code instead.

Comment: @ProfK Yes you can. `var allSuburbsList = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllSuburbs));`. Just remove the `new Array` part.

Comment: @MikeC, that's more or less what I did, so go ahead and answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Using `new Array([{}])`, you are creating an array inside another array. Just instantiate that without `new Array()`